# In Ember can I pass markup to a component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to create a dropdown type component that can have some markup for the title, and then upon hovering reveal more markup. Something like this:

```
{{#dropdown-menu}}

    {{#dropdown-header}}
        <span>My Custom Title markup</span>
    {{/dropdown-header}}

    {{#dropdown-body}}
        list of menu items
    {{/dropdown-body}}

{{/dropdown-menu}}
```

The body should only show while some property like isExpanded is true. But if the body is clicked, isExpanded would become false.

I can make a working component that accepts a title property (string), but I can't figure out how to make the title include custom markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `yield` in your component in an `if` block. see this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rirupu/7/edit)

component:

```
App.TestShowComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  layoutName: "components/test-show",
  expanded: false,
  actions: {
    toggle: function () {
      this.set('expanded', !this.get('expanded'));
    }
  }
});
```

index template:

```
{{#test-show}}
  inner stuff
{{/test-show}}
```

component template:

```
<button {{action 'toggle'}}>toggle</button>
{{#if expanded}}
  {{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have all the functionality contained in a component? If I wanted to put a bunch of these components on the page it wouldn't really work to have the functionality in the controller.

Comment: Sure just move the action and the var to the component.

Comment: Actually this is basically what I already had. What I need is for the `<button {{action} 'toggle'}}>toggle</button>` to be able to be different for different uses of the component. For example one dropdown might be a button while in another spot the heading is an image for example.

Comment: You should have asked a new question.